# unversioned files in git

Tags: git, android-studio

I add this :

```
.idea
.gradle
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
/local.properties
*.iml
gradle.properties
/.idea
.externalNativeBuild
```

into **gitignore** . so into the `unversioned files` appears some files . my question is that these files have to be in this section and can I remove from this section or I have to remove these files?

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to delete them from there? Didn't you just mark them as unversioned?

Comment: I do not want to delete them. I just ask a question that Do I have to delete them or not? and If I delete them, what is happend

Comment: I answered your question already. Please see answer.

Comment: For now, If you are not sure what files to ignore just add all -> commit -> push. Later on when you have a better understanding you would be able to choose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 'unversioned files' view is a view of what has been ignored in git. It shows you the state these files are in. If you delete them from there, they will not be ignored anymore.

If you just made them as unversioned (for some reason I guess), I doubt you want to remove them from there. So you don't "have to" delete them and you *probably* don't want to delete them either.

I suggest you read up some tutorial on GIT as I have a feeling you lack some understanding of how versioning works.

Comment: Can you provide a link to it, because I don't have a clear understanding of their purpose.

Answer (score 3):

when you add a certain file into `.gitignore` Git assigns the files into *untracked files*, and you will see those files when you run `git status`. As I understand you want to remove that you won't see them listed in git status. For that run: `git clean -f`
you will see **Removing yourfile.txt**

If you want to learn more about git, I recommend you [official document](http://git-scm.com/docs), otherwise, you may ask questions if anything is unclear.
There's also a [playground for git](https://learngitbranching.js.org/) that might be interesting.